# Unfounded compilation error in VisualStudio 2012

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio's C# compiler propmts an error that has no base:
"No overload for 'ItemSelection' matches delegate 'OnItemSelected' in MainPage.xaml"
(Or I am blind and can't see the error) Earlier project could be compiled, despite the fact that the error appeared, but now it doesn't (What is strange).
Thank You for your help.

```
//MainPage.xaml
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:WordBlock   Word="{Binding}" OnSlideOccured="OnSlide"  OnItemSelection="ItemSelection"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
//MainPage.xaml.cs
private void ItemSelection(string word)
{
    ToSearch = word;
    (Panorama.Items[0] as PanoramaItem).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    Panorama.SetValue(Panorama.SelectedItemProperty, Panorama.Items[0]);
    Panorama.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    (Panorama.Items[0] as PanoramaItem).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
//WordBlock.xaml.cs
public delegate void OnItemSelected(string word);
public event OnItemSelected OnItemSelection;
```

Comment: If previously the error was appearing but still compiling, that probably mean that this error is just an error from the designer (which don't prevent the app to build), after compiling you should check the Output windows  if this error is actually appearing there (designer error don't appear there) and if there is any other error

Comment: But now it is not compiling at all. Does the code look properly for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently event used in xaml require a first parameter of type object.
Changing the delegate to:

```
public delegate void OnItemSelected(object sender,string word);
```

and the handler to:

```
private void ItemSelection(object sender,string word)
```

seem to fix the compilation problem (or you could just use `EventHandler<string>` as the event type).